# PHP Redirect Loop

Tags: php

On my index page I have a link to my login.php page with this code:

```
      <?php     
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { 
    echo "<div id='logout'><a href='logout.php'>Logout (".$_SESSION['username'].")</a></div>";
    } else { 
    echo "<div id='login'><a href='login.php'>Login (Regular)</a></div>";
    }      
    ?>
```

On the login.php page I have

```
<?php
include('check.php');

$ref = getenv('HTTP_REFERER');

if (isset($ref)) {
  header("Location: " . $ref);
  exit;
} else {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
}
?>
```

check.php is the code for the login form and it checks the users level to make sure they can access the page. I was told that I need to add a check to see if the referral is login.php, otherwise it will go in an infinite loop and I am of course getting "This webpage has a redirect loop". However, I have no clue how to do this and I can't find any information on how to fix it. Anyone know a quick solution?

Comment: bad code bad bad code very bad code HTTP_REFERER is nothing you would want to rely on it can be very easily manipulated and isn't even set by some browsers... if anything use the session to check stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just do

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && end(explode('/',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) != 'login.php') {
  header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  exit;
} else {
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
}
```

Note that this is a simplified code - you may need to be a bit smarter than that.

Comment: Yeah, got a Fatal error: Call to undefined function on the if line.

Comment: I updated the code.  However you should actually understand the code provide and not blindly copy it.  We gladly help others, but don't like doing their work for them.

Comment: :) It worked. Thanks. Yeah, I'm trying to learn PHP but I just couldn't figure this one out. I will try and be better about that.